# Raster is being saved with no bands names despite defining them using Rasterio

Tags: python, rasterio, list, multi-band

I have an ndarray which I would like to save as rasterio raster.
I have all the information I needed (image size, transform, **band names** etc.).
The problem is that when I try to save the image as raster with the band names, the image saved correctly, but the names never saved.

This is snippet of my code:

```
#open the raster that I want to process
test=rasterio.open('gs://my_bucket/my_imgs/my_elevation/elevation_img.tif')

# access the bands names, will be used later to save the output with same bands names
names=list(test.descriptions)
names
>>>['B1_OK','B2_CK']

#read as array (need it for the processing)
arr=test.read()

####after I processed the image.....

#metadata for the image that will be saved

metadata = {
    'driver': 'COG',
    'height': arr.shape[1],
    'width': arr.shape[2],
    'count': arr.shape[0],
    'dtype': arr.dtype,
    'crs':'EPSG:4326',
    'transform': test.transform,
    'descriptions': names
    }
##save the image
with rasterio.open('/home/my/folder/git/toolim/nbs/tmp/test1.tif', 'w', **metadata) as dst:
    dst.write(arr)

#check the band names of the new image:
rasterio.open('/home/my/folder/git/toolim/nbs/tmp/test1.tif').descriptions
>>>(None,None)
```

I could not find any reason why this  happens, setting names suppose to be relatively simple, so I must do something wrong...
**My end goal: be able to use the list of names as post-processed image bands, and in general, to be able to define the bands names and to understand my mistake.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *should* work, I don't know why it doesn't. However, you can set the `descriptions` property on the open dataset and the descriptions will be saved:

```
metadata = {
    'driver': 'COG',
    'height': arr.shape[1],
    'width': arr.shape[2],
    'count': arr.shape[0],
    'dtype': arr.dtype,
    'crs':'EPSG:4326',
    'transform': test.transform
    }
##save the image
with rasterio.open('/home/my/folder/git/toolim/nbs/tmp/test1.tif', 'w', **metadata) as dst:
    dst.descriptions = names
    dst.write(arr)
```

Comment: yes, this solved the issue